# Henselization of the ring of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand example of Henselization from wiki.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henselian_ring#Henselization

It says that Henselization of the ring of polynomials localized at point $(0, \dots, 0)$ are algebraic formal power series (the formal power series satisfying an algebraic equation).

Let call ring of algebraic formal power series by $A_{Hen}$

**Question 1**: Why this ring is Henselian?

In particular I want to understand why it is local. It seems unclear for me. Consider case of one variable. Consider ideals $(x, 1  \pm \sqrt{1+x})$ in $A_{Hen}$. It seems like these ideals are proper. Consider maximal ideals $ \mathfrak{m}_{ \pm} $ such that $(x, 1  \pm \sqrt{1+x}) \subset \mathfrak{m}_{ \pm} $. Clearly $\mathfrak{m}_{ +} \neq \mathfrak{m}_{ -}$

So $A_{Hen}$ is not local.

**Question 2**:Where is mistake?

Comment: $1+\sqrt{1+x}$ is invertible (as any formal series $f$ with $f(0)\neq 0$). In fact, the maximal ideal is $(x)$. So $(x,1+\sqrt{1+x})$ is not proper.

Comment: It is invertible in ring of formal functions. The inverse is $\frac{\sqrt{1+x} -1}{x(x+2)}$. Is it an element of $A_{Hen}$ (it has $x$ in denominator)?

Comment: No, since $f(0)=2$, its inverse is a formal series. In the expression you wrote, $\sqrt{1+x}-1=x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+...$ in particular, it can be divided by x

Comment: Elements of $A_{Hen}$ are not just formal series. They are formal series satisfying "algebraic equations". I have just realised that I do not precisely understand what it means. Does this equation have to be monic?

Comment: A formal series $f$ is algebraic if there exist a polynomial $P(X,Y)$ such that $P(x,f(x))=0$. With $f=1+\sqrt{1+x}$, you can take $P(X,Y)=(Y-1)^2-1-X$. $P$ doesn't have to be monic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19126/discussion-between-quinque-and-user113969).